# Thin doesn't start rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, rvm, thin

I have a ubuntu server with rails(rvm) + nginx + thin.

Nginx is listening to porst 3000-3 and works good if I start rails manually, so I guess the problem is with thin.

I've configured thin to start 3 server instances in ports 3000,3001,3002 but they don't start and report no error.

I only have a file in /etc/thin, is this normal or am I missing something? The file is the railsapp.yml.

If I run bundle exec thin start, it runs ok.

Edit: I get an error when running:

```
thin start --all /etc/thin
```

This is the error in log:

```
/home/metaloviana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:31:in `block in setup': You have already activated rack 1.4.1, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.3.5. Using bundle exec may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
```

EDIT 2:

Problem solved. Using railsgems-bundler and rvm wrapper.

Thanks guys!

Comment: did you try `bundle exec thin start --all /etc/thin`?

Comment: It works but the init.d deamon does not

Answer (score 2):

agree with @shime.

The error log indicates rubygem found many rakes of different version, and it doesn't know which version to use.

Remember, always use "bundle exec" to execute the rake tasks, e.g.

```
bundle exec thin start 
bundle exec rake db:migrate
bundle exec rspec spec
bundle exec rails generate scaffold...
```

Comment: I've installed rubygems-bundler (thanks to a nice guy from #rvm@freenode) and thin start --all /etc/thin works.

The init.d deamon does not

Comment: thanks! but check out how many times you've written `bundle exec`. there is a [gem](https://github.com/gma/bundler-exec) that aliases it. it's pretty cool and worth checking out.